# Gmail/Google gave me a new name. How can I undo that?

Tags: gmail, youtube, google-account, username

I had a separate nickname on my primary Gmail account and my YouTube account.

I think I pressed something by accident when logging into YouTube.

Now, when I am in my email account, when I look in the upper right corner where I log out, the name next to the menu with the triangle/arrow is my YouTube name, not my email address or first name like it was. When my contacts send email to me, this YouTube name gets used instead of my first name.

I would like to change this back so that my first name displays by that menu in my Gmail account and on emails my friends send to me.

How can I do this?

Comment: Try the following link while logged into the account.  https://www.google.com/settings/account?hl=en click on `Edit` Google is pushing for RealID type system with Google+

Comment: Went there, the best I could do was edit my Google+ ( I don't use it ) profile name, which is what is being put on my emails.  I wanted to use just my first name, but it wouldn't let me.  I put in a fake last name.

Comment: Why are you against using your real name and simply locking down your Google+ profile.  You must understand its already created so its to late for that.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this link: https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/accounts (If it doesn't work, go to Gmail, click the gear icon, and click the *Accounts* tab.)

You may see different email addresses with different names, or just one, but either way, you can change the default account and/or edit the display name as needed.

Comment: I went to where you described.  In that spot, it was already set up as I like, but the Google+ ( which I don't use ) profile name is still in the corner of my email account and is still being appended to emails addressed to me.

Comment: @Steve - You already migrated to Google+ profile thus your problem.

Comment: @Steve - Sounds like you have to click on in the right corner to go to the Google+ profile page and then click on the name on top there to change it.